# VMWare Error: "No space left on device" when powering up one specific host -- even though there is space?

Tags: vmware-esxi, centos5

I have a CentOS 5.x system running on VMware ESXi 5.1.0.

Recently, I rebooted and it failed to come back up.  The error I see is:

[image]

The error is odd though because my vmware host has plenty of space available:

[image]

I can also power up other VMs on the same host/resource pool fine.  It's only this one host which is experiencing the issue.

Any thoughts on what could be going on here?

Comment: I'd be looking at the sentence `SharedArea: Unable to find testSharedAreaPtr in SHARED_PER_VM_VMX area.`

Answer (score 2):

The swap file will need to be created on power up and may be exceeding the free disk space. The error message suggests a 4GB swap file is being requested and cannot be created, are you using Thin Provisioning?

Check the location of the swap file as well, it can be changed to another datastore if insufficient space available

Check http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1030719

Answer (score 0):

USE vC Converter to do this (http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/4_0). You can convert the VM while it's powered on (just select 'Powered On...' as the source type) and in the conversion wizard, you can choose to resize the virtual disks associated with the VM.
VMware KB:
http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1004047

Answer (score 0):

If you have old snapshots, delete one then power on the machine. This will provide more space on device.